# JaCoCo Injection Error executing maven test via ssh

Tags: maven, ssh, code-injection, aix, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am attempting to set up continuous integration testing for my open source project on a remote AIX server.  I can execute tests just fine in an interactive shell:

```
$ ssh gate.polarhome.com -p 775 -l oshi 
<password dialog>
<PATH set via .profile>
$ echo $PATH
> /usr/java8_64/bin:~/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/:/opt/freeware/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:$HOME/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:.
$ cd ~/git/oshi
$ mvn test -B
```

When executing in this interactive environment using exactly these steps, the test executes properly.  However, when attempting to execute the identical commands via an SSH command line, the JaCoCo plugin fails:

```
$ ssh gate.polarhome.com -p 775 -l oshi "export PATH=/usr/java8_64/bin:~/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/:/opt/freeware/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:$HOME/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:.; cd ~/git/oshi; mvn test -B"
```

After entering password, the commands proceed through the `mvn test` but then fail with an exception:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Operating System and Hardware Information                          [pom]
[INFO] oshi-core                                                          [jar]
[INFO] oshi-core-shaded                                                   [jar]
[INFO] oshi-demo                                                          [jar]
[INFO] oshi-dist                                                          [pom]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< com.github.oshi:oshi-parent >---------------------
[INFO] Building Operating System and Hardware Information 5.3.7-SNAPSHOT  [1/5]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- git-commit-id-plugin:4.0.3:revision (git-commit-id) @ oshi-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:3.2.0:parse-version (default) @ oshi-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (enforce-maven) @ oshi-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.6:prepare-agent (pre-unit-test) @ oshi-parent ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.jacoco.maven.AgentMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jacoco.core.runtime.AgentOptions
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodsImpl (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods (Class.java:1008)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getDeclaredMethods (InjectionPoint.java:766)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints (InjectionPoint.java:683)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields (InjectionPoint.java:378)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:182)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies (InjectorImpl.java:661)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup (InjectorImpl.java:617)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding (InjectorImpl.java:603)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:932)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive (InjectorImpl.java:852)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:291)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:222)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:1040)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1071)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1034)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:508)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

(Full log available [here](https://github.com/dbwiddis/oshi/runs/1540558417?check_suite_focus=true))

Using the `-X` switch on maven, the log line immediately preceding the error is:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.6:prepare-agent from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.jacoco:jacoco
```

I have searched StackOverflow for similar issues. The closest I found was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519646/jacocoreport-error-noclassdeffounderror) with similar symptoms, but associated with a Jenkins versioning problem.

I've tried various other attempts at solutions:

- Deleted the `.m2/repository` and let it rebuild
- Added `clean` to the maven commands
- Attempted to skip JaCoCo using `jacoco.skip=true`

I'm pretty sure the issue has to do with the "injection" involved with JaCoCo, but can't figure out how to bypass, skip, or further investigate problems with this.

I'm at a loss for a next troubleshooting step.  What is different about an interactive ssh enviornment vs. `ssh` command-line that would cause different behavior from the jacoco-maven-plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there was one setting in my interactive `.profile` that was key to resolving this:

```
ulimit -n 8192
```

Seems rather than trying to copy path and other things over, just using `source .profile` would have saved me a lot of troubleshooting time.